# How do I XmlDocument.Save() to encoding="us-ascii" with numeric character entities instead of question marks?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xmldocument, xml-encoding

My goal is to get a binary buffer (`MemoryStream.ToArray()` would yield `byte[]` in this case) of XML without losing the Unicode characters. I would expect the XML serializer to use numeric character references to represent anything that would be invalid in ASCII. So far, I have:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml("<x>“∞π”</x>");
        using (var buf = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var writer = new StreamWriter(buf, Encoding.ASCII))
                doc.Save(writer);
            Console.Write(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buf.ToArray()));
        }
    }
}
```

The above program produces the following output:

```
$ ./ConsoleApplication2.exe
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="us-ascii"?>
<x>????</x>
```

I figured out how to tell `XmlDocument.Save()` to use `encoding="us-ascii"`—by handing it a `TextStream` with `TextStream.Encoding` set to `Encoding.ASCII`. [The documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sa5wd18z%28v=vs.110%29) says `The encoding on the TextWriter determines the encoding that is written out`. But how can I tell it that I want it to use numeric character entities instead of its default lossy behavior? I have tested that `doc.Save(Console.OpenStandardOutput())` writes the expected data (without an XML declaration) as UTF-8 with all of the correct characters, so I know that `doc` contains the information I wish to serialize. It’s just a matter of figuring out the right way to tell the XML serializer that I want `encoding="us-ascii"` with character entities…

I understand that it may be non-trivial to write XML documents that are both `encoding="us-ascii"` and supportive of constructs like `<π/>` (I think this one might only be doable with external document type definitions. Yes, [I have tried just for fun](http://cdn.ohnopub.net/cdn/binki/xml_pi_elem/).). But I thought it was quite common to output entities for non-ASCII characters in an ASCII XML document to support preservation of **content** and **attribute value** character data in Unicode-unfriendly environments. I thought that numeric character references representing Unicode characters was analogous to using base64 to protect a blob while keeping the content more readable. How do I do this with .NET?

Comment: If you're just checking through Console, you might want to check Console.OutputEncoding.

Comment: @tweellt But my goal was to serialize the XML to something that would survive in ASCII (which would imply it could survive whatever encoding Console.OutputEncoding is set to on an English system).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [XmlWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162618%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead:

```
  var doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.LoadXml("<x>“∞π”</x>");
    using (var buf = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (var writer =  XmlWriter.Create(buf, 
              new XmlWriterSettings{Encoding= Encoding.ASCII}))
        {
            doc.Save(writer);
        }
        Console.Write(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buf.ToArray()));
    }
```

Outputs:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="us-ascii"?><x>&#x201C;&#x221E;&#x3C0;&#x201D;</x>
```

Comment: can you please help me how to convert &#xE4; to &#x00E4; by using xmldocument library

Comment: @Karthick that is a strange wish... In any case you should ask separate question with good explanation why it is important for your text (definitely no difference from XML point of view).

Comment: yes both are same but i need to retain as it is in source xml.

Comment: please see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37160364/handling-us-ascii-encoded-xml-with-unsupported-entity-reference?noredirect=1#comment61856507_37160364

Comment: Note that you will need to strip out any CDATA sections if you use this method. CDATA is mostly treated as indistinguishable from text when consuming or creating it. However, CDATA is distinguishable from Text in the DOM and `XmlWriter` will always output CDATA if it is in the DOM. If the CDATA has non-ASCII characters in it, it is possible to encode that by closing the CDATA, writing a character entity, and then reopening. But `XmlWriter` instead fails with an encoding exception. So my workaround is an intercepting proxying `XmlWriter` implementation which just turns all CDATA into Text.

Comment: And the same goes for comment nodes.