# Saving XML file from one location to another location using XML DOCUMENT

Tags: c#, xml, xml-encoding

While saving the existing XML to new location, entities escaped from the content and replaced with Question Mark

See the snaps below entity ‐ (- as Hex) present while reading but its replaced with question mark after saving to another location.

**While Reading as Inner XML**

[image: While Reading as inner XML]

**While Reading as Inner Text**

[image: While Reading as inner Text]

**After Saving XML File**

[image: After Saving XML]

**EDIT 1**
Below is my code

```
string path = @"C:\work\myxml.XML";
string pathnew = @"C:\work\myxml_new.XML";
//GetFileEncoding(path);
XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
XmlDeclaration xmlDeclaration = document.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0","US-ASCII",null);
//document.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", null, null);
document.Load(path);
string x = document.InnerText;
document.Save(pathnew);
```

**EDIT 2**
My source file looks like below. I need to retain the entities as it is

[image]

Comment: It's almost certainly an encoding problem, but no one can help you without providing some *code* instead of pictures.  How are you writing the XML?

Comment: @CharlesMager, Thanks for your attempt. See the edited question

Comment: Is your source file *actually* US-ASCII?  Or does the declaration just say it is?  I don't think your character [exists in ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_printable_code_chart), which is why it's being replaced.  `XmlDocument` is inferring the encoding to use on save from the declaration.

Comment: Why not use [File.Copy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.copy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

Comment: @CharlesMager, yes my source file is US-ASCII encoding. pls. see here my unicode char http://unicodelookup.com/#‐/1

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, i am not copying the exact file but i need to update specific node in existing xml file

Comment: Ascii encoding removes non-printable characters.  So you can have ascii (one byte characters) that are not unicode (two byte characters) that will result in question marks.

Comment: @Karthick I'd be pretty sure your source file *isn't* ASCII.  That character doesn't exist in ASCII.  Open the file in Notepad++ or something and check the encoding.

Comment: @jdweng, Thanks for your information.how can i retain the unicode characters as it is in the source. in Source xml the unicode  hex is &#x2010;. which is nothing but hyphen. i want to retain this hex after updating the specific node and save.

Comment: @CharlesMager, yes you are right its not in ASCII category. but i need to retain the entity characters as it is in source. pls see the edited part 2

Comment: Try this : XmlDeclaration xmlDeclaration = document.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "unicode", null);

Comment: f y ou use a XmlReader you can turn the check characters off :             XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings() { CheckCharacters = false};

Comment: @Karthick it's very easy to do, but you need to know what encoding you need to write your file in.  So you need to check what it's actually encoded in.

Comment: @jdweng i tried with xmlDeclaration but not use it returns question mark

Comment: @CharlesMager i need to write UTF-8 encoding characters with US-ASCII xml

Comment: i tried to find the encoding method which is in source file its shows me as default (iso-8859-1)

Comment: 8859-1 can be unicode.  See webpage : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1

Comment: Ah, ok - your latest edit makes a lot more sense.  The file *is* ASCII encoded, but the character an entity reference.

Comment: @CharlesMager, yes your understanding is absolutely right

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I XmlDocument.Save() to encoding="us-ascii" with numeric character entities instead of question marks?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22394441/how-do-i-xmldocument-save-to-encoding-us-ascii-with-numeric-character-entiti)

Comment: As a general aside, for most XML writers, you can't "retain the entity characters as it is in source". There is no reason to use a numeric character entity if the file character set supports it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here seems to be the handling of encoding of entity references by the specific `XmlWriter` implementation internal to `XmlDocument`.

The issue disappears if you create an `XmlWriter` yourself - the unsupported character will be correctly encoded as an entity reference.  This `XmlWriter` is a different (and newer) implementation that sets an [`EncoderFallback`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.encoderfallback(v=vs.110).aspx) that encodes characters as entity references for characters that can't be encoded.  Per the remarks in the docs, the default fallback mechanism is to encode a question mark.

```
var settings = new XmlWriterSettings
{
    Indent = true,
    Encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("US-ASCII")
};

using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(pathnew, settings))
{
    document.Save(writer);            
}
```

As an aside, I'd recomment using the LINQ to XML `XDocument` API, it's much nicer to work with than the old creaky `XmlDocument` API.  And its version of `Save` doesn't have this problem, either!

Comment: Thanks for your code. I don't know why &#x00F6; converted as &#xF6;. It should be retained as &#x00F6;

Comment: As we are nearing to the expected output. really appreciate your work

Comment: @Karthick I don't think you're going to get that fine a control over the entity encoding.  Semantically, they are exactly the same.

Comment: yes ofcourse i saw in browser, is that any way to include 00 after the x?

Comment: Appreciate your great help on this. Can you please look in to this how to convert &#xE4; to &#x00E4;

Comment: As I said above, you don't get this kind of control. Unless you want to start down the road of creating a custom `XmlWriter`. They are the same thing, so it really shouldn't matter.