# Handling US-ASCII encoded XML with unsupported entity reference

Tags: c#, xml, entity, xml-entities, xml-encoding

This question is the continuation of this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37140115/saving-xml-file-from-one-location-to-another-location-using-xml-document/37142822?noredirect=1#comment61846297_37142822)

**PROCESS:** The process involved, Opening XML file and do some modification in specific nodes and save it back to another location.

**PROBLEM FACING:** While Saving after some modifications in XML, unsupported entity references like `&#x00F6;` converted into `&#xF6;`. I want to retain the entity as it is in the source (`&#x00F6;`)

As `&#xF6;` and `&#x00F6;` are same character but i need to retain as it is in source xml.

**XML SOURCE**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="US-ASCII"?>
<heads>
    <head type="TRANSFER">
        <headtext xml:lang="ENG" original="y">My Name &#x00F6;is Sinthiya</headtext>
    </head>
</heads>
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="US-ASCII"?>
<heads>
    <head type="TRANSFER">
        <headtext xml:lang="ENG" original="y">My Name &#x00F6;is Sinthiya</headtext>
    </head>
</heads>
```

**GETTING RIGHT NOW**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="US-ASCII"?>
<heads>
    <head type="TRANSFER">
        <headtext xml:lang="ENG" original="y">My Name &#xF6;is Sinthiya</headtext>
    </head>
</heads>
```

**My Code**

```
string path = @"C:\work\myxml.XML";
string pathnew = @"C:\work\myxml_new.XML";
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(path);
using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(pathnew, new XmlWriterSettings { Indent= true, Encoding = Encoding.ASCII }))
{
    doc.Save(writer);
}
```

Comment: As I said in your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37140115/saving-xml-file-from-one-location-to-another-location-using-xml-document), there's no easy fix for this. Even overriding parts of `XmlWriter` to ensure 4 chars may result in others being 'wrong'.  As they are semantically the same, what reason do you have for requiring they are lexicographically the same?

Comment: @CharlesMager, As per the instruction given by client, Entity references should be retained as it is. I don't want to override.

Comment: Writing non-normalized XML with standard libraries is very hard - would not recommend it to anyone. Putting price tag (i.e. "10 weeks to track source information in XML to keep de-normalized XML untouched during editing") would be good *starting point* for conversation with your "client".

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, Thanks. is there any other way to get solution without any libraries?